# Is there a reason i could be getting false notifications in windows 10 that my firewalls are off?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, notifications

The notifications panel on the bottom left tells me my both windows and mcafee firewall are down but when i go into windows fire wall it says it's being managed by mcafee and mcafee says its on? So why might i be getting a notification that niver is on?

Comment: It could be the version of the software your using.  Verify it specifically indicates Windows 10 support.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar happen with a different anti-virus software and windows 7 in the past, Usually after a large update to the anti-virus program. Windows stopped detecting what the anti-virus program was doing (for whatever reason),

what I did to fix it was turn **off** the firewall in my anti-virus and the windows firewall, **applied** so that windows defiantly knows the fire wall is down, then **enabled** them again so that what ever process tells windows that the firewall is online can trigger again. Hope this helps...